# How to connect to the H2 database used in Gerrit

Tags: h2, gerrit

I tried the following command, but it failed.

```
ssh -p 24198 my_server gerrit gsql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct command.  What error did you get?  Was Gerrit up and running?  It must be up and running to connect over ssh.  See http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4/cmd-gsql.html

If Gerrit is not up and running, you can use `java -jar gerrit.war gsql -d <SITE_PATH>` - see http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4/pgm-gsql.html

Comment: ssh: connect to host my_server port 24198: Connection timed out

Gerrit is running,I can push and access the web site.

Comment: It looks like your port number is wrong?  The standard port is 29418.  Are you sure you have the correct ssh port?